# how can I reduce initial loading time of a YouTube iframe video

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

how can we reduce iframe loading time? or can we lazy load youtube iframe video?

I tried to hide the iframe in start and put a image in front. When user clicks then i can show the iframe, but it takes more than one clicks to play the video.

Comment: Use the YouTube API directly and just make a fake poster image of the video to display until someone clicks it. Then load the api and hydrate the video.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `loading="lazy"` attribute iframe tag.